# Web API Resource Authorizations

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity, claims-based-identity

I'm currently building a Web API but have run into an authorization problem with GET requests.  Essentially my problem is how do I authorize requests based on the request parameters.  I've tried looking online but the only solution I can find for resource authorization is to create my own authorization filter attribute.  So lets say a client belongs to a Fac 8474, so they should be able to get `api/fac/8474`.  But what is stopping the user from getting `api/fac/8475`?  The code below uses a custom auth filter that gets the users claim value for nId.  After getting the requested record I check the nId value on the record.  If they are equal I allow access, if not I send a 401 unauthorized.  However, I will have to write this code for every route and that I don't like the thought of writing extra code for each request which might include even more logic then a simple int check.

```
class ClaimsAuthorizationFilter : AuthorizationFilterAttribute
        {
            public override Task OnAuthorizationAsync(HttpActionContext actionContext, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)
            {
                var principal = actionContext.RequestContext.Principal as ClaimsPrincipal;

                KeyValuePair<string, object> facId = actionContext.RequestContext.RouteData.Values.Where(p => p.Key == "facId").SingleOrDefault();
                Claim nIdClaim = principal.Claims.Where(p => p.Type == "nId").SingleOrDefault();

                if (nIdClaim == null) {
                    actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
                    return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
                }

                SM msg = ClientAPI.GenerateResponse("FAC_GET", Convert.ToInt32(facId.Value));
                dtoFac fac = (dtoFac)msg.Data;

                if (nIdClaim.Value != fac.nId.ToString())
                {
                    actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
                    return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
                }
                return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
            }
        }
```

I've also looked at this example http://jakeydocs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/security/authorization/resourcebased.html Essentially getting the resource then checking the nId which I also implemented and it works.

```
var identity = User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
Claim nId = identity.Claims.Where(p => p.Type == "nId").SingleOrDefault();

if (nId == null) {
     return NotFound();
}

// Get list of resources named bat

if (!IEnumAuthCheck(bat, nId.Value)) {
     return NotFound();
}

private bool IEnumAuthCheck(IEnumerable<bat> list, string nId)
    {
        foreach (bat element in list)
        {
            if (element.nId != Convert.ToInt32(nId))
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

My main question is, what if any are the recommended patterns for solving this issue?  Resource based authentication for ids seem like it would be a very common issue but there is a distant lack of articles about it.

Comment: _But what is stopping the user from getting `api/fac/8475`_ Why stop the user? Based on authorization you find a record or not. In case you don't: return NotFound. Does it add value to return 401? And if you want to prevent guessing the url: use guid's as id.

Comment: _Based on authorization you find a record or not_. Yes, so my question is, is there a recommended pattern for authorization of a record.  I looked at this example [link](http://jakeydocs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/security/authorization/resourcebased.html) and is seems that pattern people are following is 1. Retrieve the record 2. determine if userId is related to found record 3. return true / false depending on result.  4.  Perform this call for every method needing authorization.